# Как скомпилировать .java?

Tags: java, linux

Как можно в линукс скомпилировать исходный код в .class, так чтобы с указанием пути, куда надо класть выходной файл?

Answer (score 3):

На просторах интернета нашел:

> By default, "javac" will output the
> class file in the same directory as
> the source file. But you can change
> this default behavior by using the
> "-d" option. It will make "javac" to
> output the class files into the
> specified directory.

```
javac -d .\cls .\com\herong\util\PackagedHello.java
```

Comment: у меня пишет command not found в linux, мне что то надо еще устанавливать

Comment: @eldqs переменную окружения конечно же!!

Comment: @eldqs и JDK для прикола...